# Include Trailing Character for Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a Regex I made for Java that will search for the words:

```
virtue
virtues
VIRTUE
VIRTUES
```

The line of code is here:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bvirtue[s']?\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

However, I need it to include the trailing character. For example:

```
virtue's or VIRTUE'S
```

Can someone tell me what else is needed for the trailing character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
(?i)\bvirtue('?s)?\b
```

[image: regex]

Additionally, if you plan to use the regular expression very often, it is recommended to use a constant in order to avoid recompile it each time, e.g.:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bvirtue('?s)?\\b");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "virtue\nvirtues\nVIRTUE\nVIRTUES\nvirtue's or VIRTUE'S";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
virtue
virtues
VIRTUE
VIRTUES
virtue's
VIRTUE'S
```

Comment: Yours worked really good. I am actually parsing for the word virtue (case insensitive, with trailing characters) in a bunch of XML file

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is matching `virtue'` or `virtues` but not `virtue's`, that is because you have a list of possible characters and you use it at most 1 time.

probably you want this:

`/virtue'?s?/i`

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. Just add `s?` after the `?` that precedes the character class

Your new pattern should be

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bvirtue(s|'s)?\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

**output**

```
virtue
virtues
VIRTUE
VIRTUES
virtue's
VIRTUE'S
```

Comment: This allows `virtuess`

Comment: its been edited. thanks alot. A +1 would be appreciated

Comment: sorry o. I even thought what i edited was correct. Didn't proofread

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
(?i)\bvirtue'?s?\b
```

[image: regex]

Additionally, if you plan to use the regular expression very often, it is recommended to use a constant in order to avoid recompile it each time, e.g.:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bvirtue'?s?\\b");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "virtue\nvirtues\nVIRTUE\nVIRTUES\nvirtue's or VIRTUE'S";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
virtue
virtues
VIRTUE
VIRTUES
virtue's
VIRTUE'S
```

Comment: Note that this will match `virtue'` in `virtue'd`

Comment: Hi, @nhahtdh Nice find of fail case! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis in order to [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) the matches, try with:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(virtue[s']?)\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: s in virtue's is not included in the match